Quickest return from stable Earth orbit to ground?
Inspired by this Worldbuilding question about orbital deployment (deploying things to the ground from orbit): What is the quickest that something has actually deorbited and landed from a stable closed orbit around Earth, as in the least amount of time elapsed from orbiting to resting on the ground?
I'm interested in answers involving both controlled landings and uncontrolled impacts (lithobraking), if available.
For example, this article indicates that the SpaceX Crew Dragon used for Crew-7 performed a 15-minute-long deorbit burn and splashed down 37 minutes after the burn finished, so I would count that as 52 minutes from orbit to ground.

I don't know the answer to your question, but at 3g acceleration it would take 4-5 minutes to decelerate from orbital speed assuming uniform deceleration. I suspect that this is entirely impractical and does not account for air resistance properly, but perhaps is a lower limit.

How hypothetical do you want to go, and how whole the landing thing landing should be after landing? Real reentries so far focused on being safe rather than fast, so you won't get any record-breaking entries, but if you want something down quick, with some fuel you can get it down quite quick, and with aerodynamic shape and some wing surface... whoa. Now if you want it to land on the ground in one piece as opposed as scattered droplets of molten metal, you're gonna need to slow down a good bit...

I suspect for human rated/later human rated capsules the early Mercury and Vostok capsules that did ballistic re-entry may be the winners here, doing higher G-s than the later capsules that flew lofted trajectories. unsure if public facing timelines are available for them.

@GremlinWranger The Wikipedia page for Vostok 1 gives 7:25 UTC for the start of the deorbit maneuver and 8:05 for the landing, so about 40 minutes.

Just for clarity, by "landing" do you mean something along the lines of "any landing you can walk away from is a good one" or something more drastic like "Everything is air-droppable once?"

@CortAmmon Both kinds could be valid answers (controlled landings and uncontrolled impacts as the question says).

@SF. I think the original Worldbuilding question is already a pretty good place for more hypothetical answers, so I'm thinking it'd be nice for the answers here to focus mostly on actual historical occurrences.

@CortAmmon: Trying to apply the question to "rods from God"?

If the issue is quickest return time from orbit to earth surface as stated in the question, I would suggest that the biggest opportunity of reducing time to earth is reducing the time from the high atmospheric region to earth; not the initial reentry. Free fall is faster than parachute.  Powered descent followed by rapid slowdown at earth surface would be even faster.

If I can weasel on the "ground" part, it looks like the Corona film buckets took only about 20 minutes from ejection from the satellite to reaching retrieval altitude on their parachutes at 12,000 feet.

Time was moving on toward the space vehicle’s separation. The schedule for
this activation was planned to take place at 12:46 p.m.
...
Ahead of us and up 4,000 feet higher we made out an orange tint up against
the background of towering cumulus clouds. What a sight to experience. It was 1:05 p.m., just nineteen
minutes after the satellite had been reported orbiting over Alaska.

Source: Corona Star Catchers
Good info on the entry sequence here How did the Corona (Key Hole) satellites film canisters deorbit?

Wouldn't ejection take place some time earlier than the satellite being overhead? The capsule isn't dropping straight down, but still has quite some velocity in the same direction as the satellite.

@asdfex the recovery aircraft was near Hawaii. I see nothing in my post about the satellite being overhead. The "orange tint" refers to the parachute.

While I agree that Corona film buckets could be a winner, I did some orbital mechanics to estimate the time it would take for it to deorbit using some useful data found on a figure from Wikipedia.

If we assume that "retro velocity" means "delta-v of the retro burn" then had this burn been 100% retrograde, it would have slowed the vehicle down so much that it would have reentered the atmosphere (I'll define that as 70km) in 610 seconds (~10 minutes). But if we assume that the "retro angle" was 60°, this would roughly half the amount of delta-v so then it would take 1140 sec (19 minutes) to renter to 70 km.
I suspect that if we had Guinness Book of Records judges looking over our shoulders, they would insist that we add to these figures

the duration of the retro burn,
the time it takes for the capsule to decelerate in the atmosphere,
some time for the capsule to float down to retrieval altitude on its parachute, and
then some time for the plane that captures it to return to base and land.

However, these figures do roughly line up with the data from OrganicMarble's Corona Star Catchers reference.
I also think that its quite possible that in at least one case they could have executed a zero-angle retro-burn which would have reentered the capsule in ~10 minutes (plus the length of the burn).
I also looked at satellite collisions. While I suspected that a few fragments from some collisions would have reentered very quickly, it turned out that most of the debris stayed in orbit. I could find no hard evidence of any debris fragment reentering very quickly after the collision. However from this reconstruction video you can see two satellites collide at 16:56:00 and the first yellow fragment appears to stop moving at 17:07.25. So that would technically be an 11 minute and 25 second "partial deorbit" of a satellite.
